# How many times would I need to declare std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false); in a program

Tags: c++, c++11

So, I was doing some research on some ways to make my code run faster and I saw that `printf` is faster than `cout`. But, I saw that     `std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);`
makes the cout faster by desynchronizing it.

My question now is: would you need to declare this in your main and it'll work for my whole program, or do I need to place it in each function using `cout`, or do I need to place it before each `cout`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to place it only once, preferably in main, **before doing any I/O operation** [since](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio):

> If this function is called after I/O has occurred on the standard stream, the behavior is implementation-defined

Comment: Note: be careful not to I/O in the constructors of objects with static lifetime.